# Change component prop Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, state, pinia

I'm storing a data in pinia store:

> text: "Complete",

I'm passing this text as a prop to a component:

```html
<SmallButton
  :title="store.text"
  @click="markComplete()"
/>
```

Inside the component, the setup function looks like this:

```js
setup(props) {
  let newTitle = ref(props.title);
  ...
}
```

And the newTitle text is shown in a div:

```html
<div :class="text-caption q-mx-xs ">{{ newTitle }}</div>
```

Right now if the store.text is changed, the newTitle text stays the same. I also tried to use store.text inside the div, but nothing happened.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You should be able to use `{{title}}` directly in your template since it is part of the component's props. `newTitle` is only assigned during setup and is not reactive to changes to `props.title` after it is run.

Comment: state of pinia store is available throughout components why are you passing that state as prop? [Accessing state](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/state.html#accessing-the-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for **Vue3**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-t4xx8b?file=src/components/SmallButton.vue

```
<template>
  <button :title="title" @click="$emit('click')">{{ title }}</button> <br />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'SmallButton',
  props: ['title'],
};
</script>
```